# Определения взаимной задержки между двумя рядами

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

Есть код, который строит в системе координат два графика, первый наложен на второй.
Нужно определить взаимную задержку между рядами "time" из one.json и two.json и визуализировать результат. Сейчас я написал скрипт, который строит в одной системе координат два графика из файлов one.json и two.json и первый наложен на второй.
Пробовал сделать что-то наподобии  :

```
df['time'].corr(df1['time'])
```

Но график получается построить только в виде : seaborn.heatmap
а нужно что-то наподобие line step, либо plot scatter. Реализума ли такая задача средствами matplotlib ? Не до конца понимаю как это закодить...

Код:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import seaborn as sn
import json

f = open('one.json')  #red line
stage = json.load(f)
f.close()

f1 = open('two.json')  #green line
stage_1 = json.load(f1)
f1.close()


df = pd.DataFrame(stage['one'])  #red
df1 = pd.DataFrame(stage_1['two']) #green

df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time']) #convert to date_time
df1['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['time'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

sn.set()
sn.set_style("darkgrid", {'grid.linestyle': '--'})
p = sn.lineplot(x='time',y='value',color='r', data=df, ax=ax,   drawstyle='steps-pre')
p1 = sn.lineplot(x='time',y='value',color='g', data=df1, ax=ax, drawstyle='steps-pre')


red_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='red', label='one')
green_patch = mpatches.Patch(color='green', label='two')
ax.legend(handles=[red_patch,green_patch], fontsize=8)


ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.AutoDateLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y.%m.%d.%H.%m.%S.%f'))

fig.autofmt_xdate()

p.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(3))
p1.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(3))

p.set_xlabel('time', fontsize = 10)
p.set_ylabel('value', fontsize = 10)
p.tick_params(labelsize=5)

plt.show()
```

Источник данных 1:

```
"one": [
{
    "time" : "2022-06-20 00:00:03.055",
    "value" : 1.598E-4
},
{
    "time" : "2022-06-20 00:00:04.859",
    "value" : 1.5987E-4
},
{
    "time" : "2022-06-20 00:00:04.980",
    "value" : 1.5988E-4
},
{
    "time" : "2022-06-20 00:00:09.391",
    "value" : 1.5989E-4
}
```

Источник данных 2:

```
{
"two": [
    {
        "time" : "2022-06-20 00:00:03.044",
        "value" : 1.598E-4
    },
    {
        "time" : "2022-06-20 00:00:04.849",
        "value" : 1.5987E-4
    },
    {
        "time" : "2022-06-20 00:00:04.970",
        "value" : 1.5988E-4
    },
    {
        "time" : "2022-06-20 00:00:09.383",
        "value" : 1.5989E-4
    }
```

График:[image: того что получается]

Comment: Я правильно включил ваш код, но у вас еще что-то с рисунком (Figure 1) - рекомендую исправить,

Comment: тут только часть данных, может быть из-за этого. И график строится из большего количества точек + на скриншоте он масштабирован. Но вопрос скорее не об этом

Comment: В вашем примере `value` у двух рядов совпадают, вам нужно просто взять разницу между `time`. Например: `(df.time - df1.time).dt.microseconds`. Но вообще задачу нужно чётче расписать. Вас же наверняка интересует именно разница в `time` между одинаковыми `value` или всё-таки нет?

Comment: Да всё верно говорите разница в time между одинаковыми value.

Comment: И на графике это отобразить результат

Comment: Добавил: 
res = (df.time - df1.time).dt.microseconds
print('res\n', res)

2022-06-20 00:00:03.055 -  2022-06-20 00:00:03.044 = 0.11

На выходе получаю значение  10^-5 степени: 


res
 0      11000
1      10000
2      10000

Comment: График не получается построить, поменял data=df  на data=res: 

`res = (df.time - df1.time).dt.microseconds


sn.set()
sn.set_style("darkgrid", {'grid.linestyle': '--'})
p = sn.lineplot(x='time', y='value', color='r', data=res, ax=ax, drawstyle='steps-pre') `

Посмотрите пожалуйста, что то не так делаю?

Comment: Еще раз перечитал, силясь понять, что вам надо. Что вы собираетесь определять оператором df['time'].corr(df1['time']) . Если коэффициент корреляции - то формат совершенно не верный. Но даже если вы посчитаете этот коэффициент между значениями в двух столбцах -  то в результате вы получите одно число. О каком графике при этом идет речь?